Why are Ukranian town and city names so (relatively) repetitive?
I've been browsing the map of Eastern and Southern Ukraine over the recent couple of years (looking at where the war is being conducted), and I noticed a very high rate of name repetition: There are multiple towns named "Ivanivka" or "Invanivska" or "Invanivske", and same for "Kostantinivska" (one 60,000-person city in Donetsk Oblast and 5 other small towns). We have a large town named Pokrovske mirroring the city of Pokrovsk - which is not all that far away when you think about it; and if that seems a bit redundant - try the 16 other Pokrovske in Ukraine...
I know there are other places in the world where some of the same names appear more than once, but with Ukraine it seems much more common. So, assuming it's not just my misperception: Why were Ukranian towns and villages named with this redundancy? And - was there a specific period of redundant/repetitive naming, or has it been like this for many centuries?

You are talking of small villages rather than cities. When I moved from Ukraine to the US, my impression was just the opposite: it is in the US that there are so many names repetitions:-)

It's hard to prove a negative but see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_popular_place_names for examples of common place names - Ivanivka/Ivanovka is #25!

@SPavel: I don't believe that list counts same-country popularity. Regardless - are you saying those towns are named after religious saints? That would be a partial explanation.

Ivan and Constantine are saints; Pokrov is the Church Slavonic name for the Intercession.

@Alex - You'd be right too. We even have 2 states(ish) named "Washington", and pretty much every state has a Washington county. I wrote a comment on this exact subject last week. I'll see if I can't dig it up and post a copy here...

Voting to close... It's unfortunate that there's no SE for human geography questions but this is simply not framed as a history question.

If you click on each of the cities, you'll see that many have multiples in various countries. Just look at how many San Joses are in the US.

@BrianZ: Rephrased the last paragraph to address this concern.

@BrianZ I disagree that it’s not a history question. While toponymy is technically a subdiscipline of linguistics, history very much has the biggest influence of anything on it other than phonotactics and it’s impossible to answer the question properly without diving into history to a significant degree. Trying to do so would be like trying to explain without diving into history why modern English is Germanic and not Celtic, or why the issue of Catalonian independence is such a big thing in Spain.

Such repetitiveness is no less uncommon in other countries, and even more common for smaller features - like the stuff named after Lenin, Washington, de Gaulle or Ben Gurion in the respective countries. If one could define a numeric index to demonstrate Ukraine's exclusiveness, the question would become meaningful. As now it is based on a personal opinion.

@SPavel That list may have a US bias.

Should this be on [Linguistics.SE]?

@gerrit: It's a question about what happened in Ukraine, not a question about the morphology of the words or how the words developed. So, no.

@T.E.D. There are also 63 Springfields in the US. More than one per state, yet only 36 states have them.

@Barmar Is that the case for many settlement names in the US?

@einpoklum There are a handful of very common names. Washington is first, Springfield second, and Franklin third. https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/most-common-town-and-city-names-in-the-u-s-a.html

Pokrovske means 'covering place' or 'shelter' according to a google search. The most common place name in English is reportedly "Newtown". Wikipedia confirms at least that it's widely used. Neither is particularly inspired or deep. Speaking of the latter, Niu York used to be called Novhorodske [or Novgorodskoye with the Russian spelling]
between 1951 and 2021, which literally means "new city". (

The reason is that many of these places were named at will at some relatively recent point, rather than having names developed over the course of history. People typically don't show much original thinking when giving names to places at will.

One wave of such naming was the colonization by Russians in the second
half of 18th century following the liquidation of hetmanate and
Zaporizhska sech. If you go to the list of Alexandrovkas,
say in Donetsk region, most of articles that would have anything to say about history claim that they were "founded in 17** by a [low-rank Russian nobleman] to whom the land was granted" (the area being inhabited before nonwithstanding). This is similar to how San Jose and similar names lead the list of most common place names; most of them are names of colonial settlements.
There were also some waves of even more recent renamings. For example, several different Aleksandrovkas in Dnipropetrovsk region were actually German settlements and had German names: Billerfeld, Blumenhof, Herzenberg. They all have been renamed by decree, probably along with other German settlements, in the 1920s. Other waves included renaming to get rid of ancien regime connotations after revolution, naming after Lenin, Stalin, and his associates later, then renaming after these associates were executed by Stalin, renaming after de-Stalinization, and most recently de-Sovietization.


Were the "Invanika"'s, "Pokrovske"'s, and other places not named after a particularly contentious recent-historical figure, renamed multiple times as well? Or did the renamers just leave those alone as being inoffensive enough?

@einpoklum, I can only guess; I would imagine Pokrovske would have higher chance to be renamed in the 1920s because of the religious connotation (Покров refers to the Intercession of the Theotokos holiday, often via a church named after it). On the other hand, many places with neutral names were renamed by the local bureaucrats eager to show their zeal. Pokrovsk, for example, was Grishino (neutral), then had two sovietized names, then in 2016 for some reason got a name different from the original one. Go figure...

An analysis of Open Street Map confirms your suspicion - Ivanivka is indeed a disproportionately popular name in Ukraine. In this dataset, it's edged out only by Oktyabrskiy in Russia (named, naturally, after the October Revolution) and Yeniköy in Türkiye (meaning literally New Village, same as the Czech, Belarusian, Greek, Romanian, and Polish names).

However - they are not towns. There are only a handful of Ivanivkas with a population of over 1000 people. Pokrovsk is only somewhat more popular. It is not an unusual amount - consider the number of Petersburgs or Washingtons in the USA.
The Ivan in "Ivanivka" is none other than our good friend John the Baptist (Johannes in Latin) - transliterated as Ioann in Church Slavonic and later becoming Ivan during the gradual vowel reduction that accompanied the evolution into modern Slavic languages. It would have been an extremely common name and thus an easy go-to when one was functionally illiterate and needed to name a little hamlet. References to other saints like Constantine or Nicholas/Mikola abound as well, for the same reason.
Note that a lot of the place names listed in those links have a long list of alternates. A lot of those alternates would have popped up after 1917 or 1991 when the old (Tsarist or Communist) name suddenly fell out of favor. "Ivan" is the safest possible replacement, politically speaking, and one that is close at hand.
The biggest reason is, of course, that datasets like these could not have existed back in the day, outside of perhaps high-quality census offices. The average person - perhaps even the village headman - would not have known that there was another Ivanivka not too far away.


Have you tried "Ivanovka", which is just "Ivanivka" with a Russian pronunciation and might be common in Eastern Ukraine ? 2. Besides Oktyabrskiy in Russia, Yenikoy in Turkey is also above Ivanivka with 155 occurences. 3. Nice job, great map !


Ivanivka is just one example. It seems there are quite a good number of them. Also, I don't by the "golly gee, didn't know about those other Ivanivka's" - as many of them are really close-by, a few dozen Km or so. And - Ukraine is flat, mostly-open terrain, so it's not as though the other ones are "in a hostile kingdom beyond the tall mountains" or something.

@einpoklum Keep in mind that for centuries, rural Eastern Europeans were tied to the land either as serfs or collectivized farmers. There was little need to travel, but also limited travel rights.

Usually townships and villages were named after the church. For instance, all Pokrov-like places had a church dedicated to Покрова Богородицы, aka Protecting Veil of Our Lady, a very important Orthodox holiday.

@user58697 not sure how general your claim is - it appears that naming after the landowner/founder of the village is also quite common (e.g. https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Іванівка_(Генічеський_район) ; https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Іванівка_(Ровеньківський_район) ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivanivka,_Odesa_Oblast - originally Baranovka after some Baranov)

@user58697 I would not say "usually" given that the church would conventionally come after a hamlet had grown large enough to warrant it. Of course, renaming is possible, as is naming a new settlement after the nearest monastery or some cathedral with a larger area of influence.

Note that the density of repeated names in Ukraine is not even that big with 16 Ivanivkas per 100 000 sq. km, compared to the 44 Nova Veses per 100 000 sq. km in Czechia. In fact Ukraine does not even feature in the top 10 for density of repeated names in Europe.

@TimRias That is a fair point, although I wonder if it wouldn't be a better measurement to calculate the name as a proportion of all settlement names, rather than by area

@SPavel If you have the data ready, then sure. I guess the two give slightly different info. So, which one is better depends on the exact question one want to answer.

@TimRias: 1. That is just one name. There are several repetitive names. 2. Ukraine is sparsely populated. 3. Do you have links to stats about repetitive naming in Europe?

@einpoklum 1) It is the most common repeated name. (per info graphic in answer). 2)Ukraine has 2.9 Ivanivkas per million people, North Macedonia has 4.8 Novo Selos per million people. So also relative to population density is Ukraine not exceptionally repetitive in place names.  3) This is just  combining the data in the infographic with population/area data.

That Ireland statistic on the map is incorrect, there are 7 Newcastles in Ireland.

Duplicates Are Common
You might say that unique place names are the exception, not the rule. In the US, for instance, there are 91 places named "Washington" (towns, cities, unincorporated places, etc.). There are 45 places named "Franklin" and 39 named "Clinton".
The largest cities tend to be unique because they are usually founded in the places with the best resources, and thus were founded first. They were also typically founded when there was much less competition for place names. Whereas, the small towns and villages which share unoriginal, even common names, tend to be more recent (people only settled there because they had to, not because they preferred it), where it is more challenging (and less important) to come up with an original name.
Note that in the US, many of the duplicate town names occur in the same state.

Oklahoma (in fact eastern Oklahoma) has the following similarly-named places:
Tonkawa, Tahlequah, Tecumseh, Terlton, Turley, Tulsa, Talihina, Tushka, Talala, Tiawah, Tamaha, Tullahassee, Tuskahoma. Tulsa, by the way, was formerly "Tulsey", before that "Tulsee", which was probably a shortening of "Tullahassee". However, as you can see we now have one of those too.
What's going on here of course is that these are all Native American place names. Most of them from Muskogean languages. In these languages, "Tul" or similar sounds mean "town", "hasse" or similar sounds mean "old", "humma" is "red". We also have a lot of places that start with "Ok", which usually means waters (the "Okla" in Oklahoma however is apparently "People" in Chocktaw).
These Muskogean peoples were force-marched into eastern Oklahoma in the 19th Century from their homes in the SE USA, which is also covered with similar place names. Most famous is probably Tallahassee, Florida.
Being a completely unrelated language family, it has sounds common to placenames that in English are not only uncommon, but so unusual they stick out like a sore thumb. For this reason they can "all look alike" to the untrained eye. Similarly, to us Okies rather a lot of British settlement names look alike, with all their "ham"s, "shire"s, "ford"s, and "cester"s.
I suspect a similar thing is going on here. Slavic languages aren't totally unrelated to English, but still are going to have sounds they like to use for place-names that look unusual to non-Slavic speakers. If you see a bunch of names that are unusual (to your eye) but like to reuse similar sounds, that's going to stick out.

With respect - you suspect wrong. The names you provided are not similar, i.e. most people - certainly those who speak the relevant language - would not mistake any of two of those for each other. Those town names are exactly the same or differ in the grammatical formation but still based on the same name or word.

That's an interesting opinion, considering 2 of them are literally the same name.

England has Chapel-en-le-Frith (just once), and in fact English placenames have widely varying origins.

This is full of true statements but I don't see the connection to the original question, which was about identical or almost identical names, not names containing similar sounds. Am I missing something? When you say "I suspect a similar thing is going on here", where is "here"?
